# Multiply two integers without the use of any binary operators

Tags: c++

How to multiply two integers without the use of any binary operators? I know how to do that with recursion, but the recursion would make use of "==".

Comment: Use the `*` operator? Please clarify the question.

Comment: @Phonon: Pretty much this. Worthless question with a worthless answer.

Comment: @Phonon that's a binary operator, it takes 2 arguments

Comment: If you're trying to be super creative, you could use a loop and the + operator.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by binary operators? Are you talking about bitwise operators... ?

Comment: wiki defines a binary operator as a operator that takes two operants http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation ... I'm guessing thats now what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. Assignment is a binary operator, so you basically can't use temporary variables. Comparison operators except for the implicit `== 0` and `!= 0` are all binary. Given ternary operators, it may be doable, but it certainly won't be efficient...

Comment: @Phonon: Unary operators are e.g. -<num>, +<num>, *<pointer>, &<pointer>; Binary operators are e.g. <num>+<num>, <num>*<num>; the one ternary operator is x?y:z

Comment: Yes, I misread it. I will go and die in a cave now. = )

Comment: @phresnel:  Don't forget that ++ and -- are unary operators too, which may play useful in this exercise.

Comment: @Borealid: You can use temporary variables without assignment: use the constructor-like syntax; and there's no such a thing as implicit `==0` and `!=0` in C++.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: Of course there's such as thing as an implicit comparison with zero; when you evaluate a variable in a boolean context, that's what you're doing. Zero is false, everything else is true.

Comment: @Borealid: no. There's an implicit conversion to *bool*. And then you can argue about and implicit comparison to true. But even that makes little sense. What does it do with the result of that comparison? Compares it to true again? See the comments in my answer.

Comment: `char tab[x][y]; return sizeof(tab);`

Answer (score 10):

You can do this for unsigned integers [using *only* the increment and decrement](http://www.ideone.com/rnPAb) operators:

```
unsigned x(?), y(?);
unsigned r(0);
while(x--) {
    unsigned z(y);
    while(z--) {
        r++;
    }
}
```

These are the tricks I used above to avoid using binary operators, and still get equivalent effects:

- Initialize the variable with the constructor-like syntax: no need for the symbol of the assignment operator (just in case someone unknowingly claims that kind of initialization is an assignment);
- Use increment and decrement instead of adding or subtracting one;
- Take advantage of implicit conversion of integral types to bool to use in the conditions of the cycles: this way I can compare with 0 with using operators;

The algorithm works by making the body of inner loop run `x * y` times. It's obvious that the outer loop runs `x` times. The inner loop always runs `y` times, because I took care never to change the value of `y`, by copying it into another variable (again, without using the assignment operator). Thus the end result is that `r` is incremented `x * y` times, giving us the desired result.

Comment: Isn't assignment a binary operation?  And the comparisons are comparing with zero, so they're binary too.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: An implicit conversion to bool is not the same as a comparison with zero

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: What? In if-statements, there is no implicit comparison to true within the scope of The C++ Programming Language: `expressions [...] will be [...] converted to other types in several contexts: [...] (for an) if statement [...] The destination type is bool`, and about `The if stastement`: `If the condition (6.4) yields true the first substatement is executed`. Whether there is a comparison or not a) is implementation dependent, and b) doesn't matter as the standard does not mention such comparison.

Comment: In view of continued comments, I'm deleting my previous one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
x * y:

result = 0
while(x--)  
    while(y--)
        result++;

result = (x<0) ? result * -1 : result
result = (y<0) ? result * -1 : result
```

*using help from Martinho*

Comment: The `<` operator is binary, as well as the `*` operator used at the end.

Comment: Moreover, if `x` or `y` is `< 0`, you will decrement them until an underflow occurs.

Comment: Nevermind the use of binary operators like `*` and `<`. Your loops only count to `y`, not to `x*y`.